# Getting Conflicting URI templates errors when trying to add resource class

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, tomcat7

I have a restfull implementation using Jersey and Tomcat7. I have 3 resources called RegionService, ClientService and NoteService defined in my campher.rest package.

When I try to add another resource called TestResource, and Tomcat starts, it gives me the following error below. I don't understand how /{notes} conflicts with /{test}??
Please help, my hair will thank you.

```
Aug 22, 2012 2:23:39 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class campher.rest.NoteService
  class campher.rest.ClientService
  class campher.rest.TestResource
  class campher.rest.RegionService
Aug 22, 2012 2:23:39 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Aug 22, 2012 2:23:40 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.12 02/15/2012 04:51 PM'
Aug 22, 2012 2:23:40 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Conflicting URI templates. The URI template /{test} for root resource class campher.rest.TestResource and the URI template /{notes} transform to the same regular expression /([^/]+?)(/.*)?
Aug 22, 2012 2:23:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
```

Here are the skeleton implementations of those 4 services.

```
package campher.rest;
@Path("regions")
public class RegionService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response regions() {}

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Region addRegion(Region region){}

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Region updateRegion(Region region){}

    @GET @Path("{id}")  
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getRegion(@PathParam("id") long id) {}

    @DELETE @Path("{id}")   
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response deleteRegion(@PathParam("id") long id) {}

    @GET @Path("{id}/clients")  
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getClients(@PathParam("id") long id) {}
}



package campher.rest;
@Path("clients")
public class ClientService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response clients() {}

    @GET @Path("{id}")  
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getClient(@PathParam("id") long id) {}

    @GET @Path("{id}/notes")    
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getNotes(@PathParam("id") long id) {}

    @GET @Path("{id}/alerts")   
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAlerts(@PathParam("id") long id) {}

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Client addClient(Client client){}

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Client updateClient(Client client){}

    @DELETE @Path("{id}")   
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response deleteClient(@PathParam("id") long id){}
}

package campher.rest;
@Path("{notes}")
public class NoteService {  
    @GET @Path("{id}")  
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getNote(@PathParam("id") long id) {}

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Note addNote(Note note){}

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Note updateNote(Note note){}

    @DELETE @Path("{id}")   
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response deleteNote(@PathParam("id") long id) {}     
}

package campher.rest;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
@Path("{test}")
public class TestResource {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Path("test")
```

will match `<web-root>/test`

```
@Path("{test}")
```

will match `<web-root>/foo` and `<web-root>/bar`. The word test here is merely the path-param map key to associate `foo` and `bar` values.

Notice the presence and absence of `{}` around the names. They completely change the meaning of the expression. Their presence indicates that you want to extract that out and put it in an instance variable annotated with `@PathParam("name-between-brackets")`.

Your `@Path("{test}")` and `@Path("{notes}")` both are essentially asking Jersey to look for root URLs of the form `http://<host:port>/<webapp>/{capture-text}` and copy the `capture-text` into `test` and `notes` path variables respectively. This is ambiguous.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why does my @Path("{regions}") and @Path("{clients}") and @Path("{notes}") not pose the same problem here. They work fine if I go and delete that testresource?

Comment: You have `@Path("regions")` and not `@Path("{regions}")`. Notice the missing brackets `{}`. The brackets change the meaning of the expression completely.

Comment: Wow, I never knew that. Didn't event notice the brackets. Pretty please create another answer that reflects this comment and I'll mark it as the answer. Worked perfectly. I never knew you could map a "value" param on the class level.